# How to insert backslash (\) in CKEditor so that it can be saved in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very strange problem. I have tried my best to explain it in a better way. Note that I am working in PHP/MySQL. Here is the issue:

I am trying to insert backslash (\) in CKEditor by using escape sequence which will be further saved in the database. I am inserting following piece of code in source view of CKEditor:

```
<pre>
    <code>
    D:\\Movies\\Hollywood
    </code>
</pre>
```

The HTML view of CKEditor interprets above code to:

```
D:\\Movies\\Hollywood
```

The above information is saved correctly in the database with no issue because the all backslashes are correctly escaped via escape sequence.

The output on front end comes out to be:

```
D:\Movies\Hollywood
```

But afterwards, a strange issue arises. When I press Enter key by keeping focus on address bar of my browser, the below information:

```
D:\\Movies\\Hollywood
```

automatically changes to

```
D:\Movies\Hollywood
```

It means all the escaped sequences are removed automatically permanently. Now if I go to save the information in the database then obviously it won't be saved to what I exactly wanted. It becomes

```
D:MoviesHollywood
```

Thus the escaped sequences are removed from CKEditor and consequently the backslashes are removed from front end.

Can anyone please explain this phenomenon? Why is it happening so? How can we fix it?

Comment: Your post has been deleted! Please aware of the fact that I am inserting the information in the CKEditor window and not in .php file. All the information is then grabbed and put into the db.

Comment: Not the same value but with single backslash. Double backslash is just for escaping the backslash to ensure it gets stored fine in db.

Comment: oh dear your are not understanding simple things. why are you overthinking? Please re-read my entire question again that will help you to get better understanding of my problem.